# Can these propositions be equivalent?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

We all know that:

$P \rightarrow Q $

and

$(Not)Q \rightarrow (Not)P$

are equivalent.

Is it possible that in specific cases
$P \rightarrow Q $ 
is equivalent with
$Q \rightarrow P $ 
or
$(Not)Q \rightarrow P $ 
or
$P \rightarrow (Not)Q $

Can this happen or is that impossible? If it is, how should I attempt to prove it?

Comment: NO; [logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) means that "they have the same truth value in every model" (in the case of propostoonal logic : in every truth assignment.

Answer (score 0):

From a truth table $P\to Q$ is equivalent to $Q\to P$ iff $P=Q$, to $\neg Q\to P$ iff $Q$, and to $P\to\neg Q$ iff $P\land Q$. You can easily choose $P,\,Q$ to achieve these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as two statements being 'sometimes logically equivalent' or 'possibly logically equivalent'. Logical equivalence means *always* having the same truth-value.  If it's not *always*, it's not equivalence.